# GPA when having extra courses

Tags: phd

I'm from Europe and would like apply for PhD in the USA. On my university it is mandatory to take 70 credits of courses in order to finish a master's degree. However, I decided to take extra courses to push my GPA.

How is that managed?
I can write my 'better GPA', but still I'm obligated to send all my grades.

Comment: It may help to keep in mind that in U.S. colleges and universities, course credit requirements are **minimum** requirements, and the best students often go well beyond this minimum. Indeed, in math at least (what I know most about), I would be extremely surprised if **anyone** who was accepted for admission to a U.S. top 10 math graduate program in the last couple of decades only took the minimum math requirements for a math degree at their college/university. And probably a large majority took more than the minimum number of courses overall for their degree.

Answer (score 3):

US universities will likely expect you to report your overall GPA, not just the GPA of your "best X credits". Having extra courses can still improve your overall GPA if you have better than your average grades in those courses.

If your institution allows you to report some other official GPA based on your best courses (I've never heard of this; maybe it happens, though?), you may be able to justify doing so, but should still make clear how this GPA was calculated.

As you mention, schools you apply to will likely expect to see your entire transcript, so if you try to mess with numbers to make yourself look better than your transcript indicates, you're going to get caught and you don't want to get caught inflating your application.

Comment: Some may ask for your GPA in your major as well, but will expect to see a complete transcript.

Answer (score 1):

Your GPA is the average of the grades or marks you earned as part of a degree.  No more, no less.  If your university awarded you a degree for completing x courses, and you take another course later, the additional course does not change your GPA.  If your university awards you a degree for completing x+1 courses when only x courses were required, then the additional course does change your GPA.

This is why American universities only award a degree to a student who has met the course requirements if the student also applies for graduation.  Otherwise, they are permitted to include more courses in their degree, if they pay for them.